# Connecting firebase to ionic3 app

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am trying to connect Firebase to an Ionic 3 app. I have installed the Firebase library and imported all the requirements needed, but I have this error:

`Runtime Error Uexpected value 'AngularFiredatabase' imported by the module "AppModule' please add @NgModule annotation`

Comment: Have you tried following some tutorial? You can have a loot at this **[link](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a629d9880aca7059c142976/build-ionic-3-angular-5-and-firebase-simple-chat-app)**

Comment: Shouldn't `AngularFiredatabase` be `AngularFireDatabase`?

Comment: import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
 import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

Comment: Without some code we cannot judge what you did wrong. Could you provide your AppModule and maybe other relevant pieces of code in the question? Please check out the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to ask questions we can answer more easily

Comment: i cant post codes becz of the restriction of words

Comment: Can i chat you , if yes provide me ur email

Comment: I cannot, I just don't have the time for it. My recommendation is to follow tutorials really carefully, step by step.

Comment: Thats done, It works now. But now have another error in app/app.module.ts;
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
'AngularFireDatabase' is declared but its value is never used.

Comment: Well it exaclty what the error says. You never use `AngularFireDatabase`

Comment: You mean that the AngularFirebase is installed successfully but didnt use it, right ?

Comment: Yes. You have to use `AngularFireDatabase` somewhere. For example in the constructor of a component `constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) { }`